# VeeValidate(vue.js) image file size and dimensions validation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

How to set validation in form like this using vee validate in vue.js

- Image dimension less then 500*500 pixel
- Image size less then 100kb

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For two of those requirements, there are available ("native") rules:

- Must be an image, use [**`image` rule**](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#image).
- Image size less then 100kb, use [**`size:100` rule**](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#size).

Now, for the

- Image dimension **less** than 500*500 pixels

...the problem is with the *less*.

The [**`dimensions` rule**](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#dimensions) test for **exact** size. So you'll need to tweak it to test for size smaller than or equal to the size.

A simple solution would be to take the code from the [official implementation of the  `dimensions` rule](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/2.0.6/src/rules/dimensions.js) and change it to test for *smaller or equal to*.

That's what the **demo below** does. It creates as `maxdimensions:500,500` rule.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

// based on https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/2.0.6/src/rules/dimensions.js
// and https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/2.0.6/locale/en.js#L18
const maxDimensionsRule = {
  getMessage(field, [width, height], data) {
      return (data && data.message) || `The ${field} field must be UP TO ${width} pixels by ${height} pixels.`;
  },
  validate(files, [width, height]) {
    const validateImage = (file, width, height) => {
    const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.onerror = () => resolve({ valid: false });
        image.onload = () => resolve({
          valid: image.width <= Number(width) && image.height <= Number(height) // only change from official rule
        });

        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
    };
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      // if file is not an image, reject.
      if (! /\.(jpg|svg|jpeg|png|bmp|gif)$/i.test(files[i].name)) {
        return false;
      }
      list.push(files[i]);
    }
    return Promise.all(list.map(file => validateImage(file, width, height)));
  }
};


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    this.$validator.extend('maxdimensions', maxDimensionsRule);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>


<div id="app">
   <form role="form" class="row">      
        My File: <input name="My File" v-validate data-vv-rules="image|maxdimensions:500,500|size:100" type="file"><br>
        <span v-if="errors.has('My File')">{{ errors.first('My File') }}</span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's work properly

Comment: can you have a look at a vee-validate related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444033/vue-js-bootstrapvue-veevalidate-cannot-validate-datepicker ?