# VueJS - Validate file size requirement in form file upload

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using a Bootstrap Vue form to make a simple form where user can upload a file. Is there a way to validate the size of files selected using Vue form ?

I want to prevent user from uploading such files.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370934/veevalidatevue-js-image-file-size-and-dimensions-validation) solution but looks like it includes some third party plugin. I prefer a solution which doesn't

Comment: Validation, particularly this type of validation, should be performed on the receiving server and errors sent back and displayed by the client. The client should not be responsible for validating user input; keep in mind that your application is not the only door to your server.

Comment: @Marty Yeah thanks I did not think about the possibility of other clients. But what do you mean by "...particularly this type of validation..." ? What is different about files that a server validation is preferable ? I mean it even requires a file upload which could've been avoided.

Comment: Uploading a file has many more security considerations than plain text input.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a generic Vue example of how to validate the file's size before the form is submitted.

The crux is obtaining the file object from the `files` property on the input itself, and checking the file's size via the `size` property; the rest is just stuff related to preventing the form from being submitted if the validation fails.

It goes without saying, but it is important that any kind of input validation such as this should be done on the server first and foremost; client-side validation enhances the user experience but provides no security.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onSubmit(e) {
      const file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
      
      if (!file) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('No file chosen');
        return;
      }
      
      if (file.size > 1024 * 1024) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('File too big (> 1MB)');
        return;
      }
      
      alert('File OK');
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form @submit="onSubmit">
    <input type="file" ref="file">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why do you say "..it doesn't provide any security". Is there some security related drawback to checking file-sizes this way ?

Comment: What I mean by that is the same request can be made to your server outside of the web browser, for example by using [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), and an attacker could send a gigantic file that way. This is why the server *must* validate the request.

Comment: how about file name @DecadeMoon, want to check file name only for checking images ?