# how to make a maximum 1MB upload image?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

how to make a maximum 1MB upload image?
here are the program snippets

[image: Form Item]

[image: Javascript Function]

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52143339/8003007

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Codes are text so post them as text. It would also make it easier for potential helpers to copy your code to their own editors so that they can reproduce the problem. Please see the **Code Blocks** section of the [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) help page.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine upload or not in `before-upload`. If image's size less than 1MB, cancel the upload.

```
<el-upload>
  :before-upload="isImageValid"
</el-upload>

methods: {
  isImageValid(image) {
    const imageSize = image.size / Math.pow(1024, 2)
    if (imageSize < 1) return false
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with this?

 "205:30  error  Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression  no-unneeded-ternary"

"return imageSize > 1 ?true : false"

Comment: Maybe I forget to add parentheses.

Comment: the error remains the same is there any other method besides that?

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: It's complaining because you can also simply do `return imageSize > 1;` the condition is boolean by nature. But also you can just make ESLint stop complaining....